# Searching for the index of certain elements in a list of list of list

Tags: python, list

```
test_list =[[[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,3],[0,0,0,5],[0,0,0,6]],[[0,0,0,4]],[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]]]

check_for_test = [6,4,1]
```

I want to find the index of the list which contains the element from check_for_test in test_list.

test_list and check_for_test are already sorted so that the value 6 from check_for_test can only occur in first part `[[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,3],[0,0,0,5],[0,0,0,6]]` of test_list.

The same is true for the value 4 which can only occur in the second part `[[0,0,0,4]]` and for the value 1 which can only occur in the third part `[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]]` of test_list.

My approach:

```
def index(source_list, to_find):
    index_finder = []
    for lists in test_list:
        index_finder.append([(i, item_list.index(to_find)) for i, item_list in enumerate(source_list) if to_find in item_list])
    return index_finder

deep_index = index(test_list, check_for_test)
print(deep_index)
```

Current Output:

```
[[], [], []]
```

Desired Output:

```
[[(0,3)], [(1,0)], [(2,1)]]
```

Comment: am trying to understand your question, but couldn't what do u want exactly ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use this

```
def index(seq, target):
    res = []
    for (i_idx, i), t in zip(enumerate(seq), target):
        for j_idx, j in enumerate(i):
            if t in j:
                res.append([(i_idx, j_idx)])
                break
    return res
```

Or this nested list comprehension (same output but not exactly equivalent performance due to the absence of `break`).

```
def index(seq, target):
    return [[(i_idx, j_idx)] for (i_idx, i), t in zip(enumerate(seq), target) for j_idx, j in enumerate(i) if t in j]
```

For the input you have shown

```
test_list = [[[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,3],[0,0,0,5],[0,0,0,6]],[[0,0,0,4]],[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]]]

check_for_test = [6,4,1]

print(index(test_list, check_for_test))
```

Output

```
[[(0, 3)], [(1, 0)], [(2, 1)]]
```